# map an array to table where one of those column should be mapped with another array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have table with one text field and one select element. I have to map the data in `arr1` to the table but in that table the select element should have options mapped with `arr2`.

I have an array `arr1=[{user: "John", code: "ABC"}, {user: "Nick", code: "BCD"}]` which I am going to map to the table .

I have another array `arr2=[{desc: "ABC:desc1"},{desc: "BCD:desc2"}, {desc: "CDE:desc3"},{desc: "DEF:desc4"}]` which I have to map as the options in the select.

Below the Table I have an add row button which will create an empty row with text field and preloaded options from arr2 but value is not selected as this is the new line.

I am successful in mapping arr1 and getting the right values to the table but for me the select is the tricky part. please give me any suggestions how to achieve this task. Thanks

```
<Table striped bordered condensed responsive hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Users</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.arr1.map((row, index) => {
                    return (
                        <tr key={index}> 
                            <td>
                              <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange1(index, 'user', e.target.value)} 
                                     type='text' 
                                     className='form-control'
                                     value={this.state.arr1[index].user}/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Form.Control
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange2(index, e.target.value)} id={row} as="select" size="sm">
                              <option key={""}>{""}</option>
                              {this.state.arr2.map(vals=>
                                <option key={vals.desc} value={row.code}>{vals.desc}</option>)}
                            </Form.Control>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                    })}
                </tbody>
                </Table>
                <Button className="add-btn-table" variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleAddNewItem1}>+ Add Line</Button>
```

Comment: please add the wanted result and the code, you tried.

Comment: I have added my code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in `arr2` array format, the first and the third object of the array don't have the proper closing braces.

I've tried to render with your logic using native HTML elements and it worked.

```js
  const arr1 = [
    { user: "John", code: "ABC" },
    { user: "Nick", code: "BCD" }
  ];
  const arr2 = [
    { desc: "ABC:desc1" },
    { desc: "BCD:desc2" },
    { desc: "CDE:desc3" },
    { desc: "DEF:desc4" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Users</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {arr1.map((row, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={arr1[index].user}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <select
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange2(index, e.target.value)}
                    id={row}
                    as="select"
                    size="sm"
                  >
                    <option key={""}>{""}</option>
                    {arr2.map((vals) => (
                      <option key={vals.desc} value={row.code}>
                        {vals.desc}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button
        className="add-btn-table"
        variant="secondary"
        onClick={this.handleAddNewItem1}
      >
        + Add Line
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Edit ecstatic-mccarthy-69kms]

Comment: Sorry didn't work. only users names are displayed in each row. I also need those codes to be displayed with matching prefix in the list of values. Thanks for trying.